# neo4j-import tool/csv files

Tags: csv, emacs

I'm trying to import some nodes+relationships using neo4j-import but seem to have encountered some problems. I went into the bin directory, where the import tool is hosted, and typed in the following:

```
./neo4j-import --into graph.db --nodes CLass.csv --nodes Company.csv --nodes Person.csv --nodes ResearchField.csv --nodes ResearchGroup.csv --nodes project.csv --relationships rels.csv
```

Below are the a snapshot of my files when I type in "emacs":
Class.csv:

```
ClassId:ID,name,:LABEL
3,Discrete Mathematics,Class
4,Introduction to Digital Design,Class
5,Solar System Physics,Class
```

Company.csv

```
CompanyId:ID,name,:LABEL
395,AirForce,Company
396,MITRE Corporation,Company
397,Lockheed Martin,Company
```

The other nodes are structured in a similar way. As for emacs rels.csv, this is what I have:

```
:START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE
422,446,Directs
422,447,researches
422,430,researches
```

However, when I tried to execute, this error message is returned: ]

```
Input error: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 item, but had 0 ([])
```

...and if I remove the "./" in the beginning, this is returned:

```
bash: neo4j-import: command not found
```

Can you guys let me know what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the capital `L` in your filename (`CLass.csv`) which might cause it to find nothing.

Otherwise I would try it with only one `--nodes` argument at a time to figure out which file is the problem and go from there.

The `./` is definitely needed as that is how you execute binaries on *NIX-style systems